# Trigger event via jQuery in webpack and handled on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

I am in the process or overhauling a very large application to React. I have a form that is handled in React (and bundled with webpack). On a successful form submission, I need to refresh a datatable on the page (which is not handled by React/Webpack). I attempted to just register a listener on the page and fire the event in React via jQuery but the event doesn't register with the lisenter. Am I doing anything wrong?

In webpack plugins (not using a dev server):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}),
```

In my React code:

```
handleCreated = () => {
  $(document).trigger('reload:datatable');
  // ...
}
```

On the page (in a script tag):

```
$(document).on('reload:datatable', function (e) {
  console.log('reload.task.table'); // This never gets called
});
```

Comment: I believe using jQuery with React is not recommended - jQuery modifies the DOM directly, whereas React works with a virtual DOM.

Comment: I'm second to Toby, you cannot use jquery events with React

Comment: My 2 cents: make sure you register the listener before mounting the React form

Comment: @Toby While I agree that it's not "preferred" to mix React w/ jQuery there are instances where you don't have much of a choice (i.e., converting a legacy project). However, this is what makes React great, you can take over sections of the page until you can eventually convert everything over.

Comment: @TudorIlisoi If I create a new CustomEvent (using a polyfill for older browsers) it works! Not sure why it doesn't work w/ jQuery events, but if you want to create an answer w/ your comment I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: @csm232s Did you got any work around on this?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a super old question, but the answer might not have anything to do with React, but rather jQuery's behavior and how it Webpack bundles code. The jQuery instance reference you get within Webpack is not generally shared with global - that means unless you shared that instance globally, your document script tag level code might be executing against a different jQuery instance. If you did something like reference jQuery directly in your imports and then include jQuery globally for your in-line code to execute, you're getting two different instances of jQuery with two different custom event queues.

If I did something like this pseudo code

```
// include jQuery on the page
... <script src="jquery.js" /> ...

// register a custom event listener
$(document).on('example:thing', () => { console.log('test'); });

// load jQuery onto the page again (such that the original jQuery instance is overwritten)
... <script src="jquery.js" /> ...

// trigger the custom event
$(document).trigger('example:thing');
```

The result would be that nothing would happen - the custom event would not fire. Custom Events in jQuery are stored and processed within the jQuery instance, not the DOM. In order for a jQuery custom event to be registered and triggered, both events need on the same instance of jQuery.